# Leaves of my mango plat are turning brown from the edges

Tags: leaves, mango

[image]
[image]
[image]

In the last few days, the leaves of my mango plat have started to turn brown from the edges, and it's happening only in one plant, the other 3 plants just right to the infected(?) one are alright.

I must mention recently the temperature has reached 42 Degree Celcius, and these are all potted plants with a drip watering system.

Could it be just a water requirement or something else?